# Using horizontal scroll commands without setting `nowrap`

Tags: scrolling

I tend to use a lot of vertical splits in my vim (version 8.1, via Arch Linux official repos) usage (on top of tabs, horizontal splits, tmux, etc.), and it gets frustrating when many of my lines wrap and eat up vertical real-estate when there's plenty of indent-borne whitespace.

I want to be able to read the tail of my code, but I also don't want those indents to eat up proportionally huge amounts of real-estate when I have vertical splits.

Now, I know I can use horizontal scroll commands (e.g. `zh`, `zl`) when I have `nowrap` set in Vim. These commands, however, seem to be disabled when I set `wrap`.

How can I get the same effect with `wrap` set (or similar)?

i.e. having the tail of the text wrap to the first visible column and still have horizontal scroll commands

Comment: Do you mean `zh`, `zl`, & co.?

Comment: Yes, those commands (edited question to clarify). They don't appear to function when I have `set wrap` in play. I'd be fine with solutions involving other convenient commands.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: That would be important information, wouldn't it... Version 8.1. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: From the docs: “only works when `'wrap'` is off”

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. :-(  But I have my fingers crossed for a workaround or a plugin or *something* that, in spite of that, helps me get the whitespace shifted away while simultaneously being able to read the tail end of my code.